# How do phase carries structural information about the function?

Tags: acoustics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Suppose you are on a railway platform and you hear the sound of train coming towards you. Now, Using Fourier transformation we can convert the time domain function (here take  sound as a function) into the frequency domain.

I have heard that **location (structural) information of a function in the time domain is tightly coupled with phase information in the frequency domain**. So can anybody help me to understand the above statement given in bold letters with the help of above example?

Also, can we find that whether train is coming  towards you or going away from you from the phase information of the sound function?

Comment: Can you find physical examples which can enlighten you about a rather poorly conceived phrase? How about the source of the phrase?

Comment: This seems like a list-based question, which is not a good fit for this Q&A site. Could you rephrase your question to be less broad?

Comment: Your question can be answered by a large variety of answers; this site prefers one *canonical* answer. But to get your (one) answer, you need to focus the question to an application that you are *most* interested in.

Comment: Your cellphone. Your laptop using wireless to connect to the internet. The communications signals from the rovers and probes sent to Mars, Comet 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko, Ceres, and Pluto. So long as the magnitude is above some noise floor, it's the frequency and phase that's more important. That's where the signal lies.

Comment: @Kyle I have made some changes in the question. is it still broad one?

Comment: @John I have made some changes in the question. is it still broad one?

Comment: @LDC3 I have made some changes in the question. is it still broad one?

Comment: @user3559780 I thought your question was answerable and did, please comment if that's generally what you were after?

Comment: @paisanco you have given a very good answer . I don't understand why my question is still put on-hold. So I am trying to make it fit on the site.

Comment: It's up to the users with over 3000 rep to decide if it can be reopened. They may feel it needs more edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things simple, let's talk about plane acoustic waves in one dimension.

If we solve the wave equation in one dimension , we find that the acoustic pressure as a function of space and time is of the form

$$P(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx -\omega t)}$$

where $A$ is the maximum amplitude, $x$ and $t$ are the displacement and time respectively, $\omega$ is the frequency, and $k= \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the ***wavenumber*** (where $\lambda$ is the wavelength). $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Notice that both the spatial and temporal variation of the acoustic pressure are information carried in the ***phase*** (the exponentiated term) , not the magnitude (amplitude).

Now let's talk about Fourier transforms. One can take a Fourier transform from the time domain to the frequency domain, or vice versa. In our simple example, there is only one frequency, but real sound is usually composed of a mix of frequencies (like human speech for instance). So the Fourier transform from the time to the frequency domain is key in understanding what frequencies a complex acoustic signal is composed of.

But note something else. As is suggested by the exponential form above, we can equally well do a Fourier transform from the ***spatial*** domain to the ***wavenumber*** domain, or vice versa. And this fact, turns out to be key in analyzing the spatial structure of a signal in terms of the superposition of wavenumbers (which, remember, are related to wavelengths) found in that signal.

As just a simple example, imagine we wanted to make a line array of microphones that is sensitive to signals coming from a certain direction. It turns out that if we apply weight vectors to each microphone to "steer" it to a certain direction $\theta$, the solution looks an awful lot like the expression for a spatial-wavenumber Fourier transform:

$$
D(\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w_n \exp\left(iknd \sin(\theta) \right).
$$

where $w_n$ are the weights applied to each microphone, $n$ just is an integer that labels each microphone, and $d$ is the microphone spacing.

So to sum it up, the phase carries both spatial and temporal information about the signal, and the respective Fourier transforms carry information about the frequency structure and wavenumber structure of the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider reading about [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect). This is one of those cases, where the phase of the wave function, in sum with the electromagnetic 4-potential, is extremely important, as it gives different physical results. This effect was also [checked experimentally](https://scholar.google.ru/scholar?q=aharonov+bohm+effect&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=_teOVeudB8GysQGSmYHgAQ&ved=0CBkQgQMwAA), so it is not a pure theoretical abstraction.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be relevant to an acoustics question.

Comment: @Hayk I have made some changes in my question. can you answer accordingly?